# Firebase.AuthSateListener not running when trying to login

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a basic messaging app for school and I'm trying to use firebase authentication to allow users to log in to their accounts.

I would appreciate anybody looking through my code and pointing out anything obviously wrong or telling me if there's anything I can do to try to solve the problem because I have no idea what's wrong with it.

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnSubmitLoginPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitLoginPage);
    final EditText edtUsernameLoginPage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsernameLoginPage);
    final EditText edtPasswordLoginPage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPasswordLoginPage);

    btnSubmitLoginPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showToast("1");
            FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    showToast("2");
                    Authenticate(edtUsernameLoginPage, edtPasswordLoginPage, txtErrorLoginPage);
                }
            showToast("14")
            };

        }
    });
} //end of main activity

private void Authenticate(EditText edtUsernameLoginPage, EditText edtPasswordLoginPage, final TextView txtErrorLoginPage) {
    showToast("3");
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        showToast("You are logged in");
        showToast("4");
    } else {
        showToast("5");
        String strUsername = edtUsernameLoginPage.getText().toString();
        String strPassword = edtPasswordLoginPage.getText().toString();
        if (strUsername.isEmpty()) {
            txtErrorLoginPage.setText("Username is empty");
            showToast("6");
        } else if (strPassword.isEmpty()) {
            txtErrorLoginPage.setText("Password is empty");
            showToast("7");
        } else if (strPassword.isEmpty() && strUsername.isEmpty()) {
            txtErrorLoginPage.setText("Both are empty");
            showToast("8");
        } else if (!(strPassword.isEmpty() && strUsername.isEmpty())) {
            showToast("9");
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(strUsername, strPassword).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    showToast("10");
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        showToast("11");
                        txtErrorLoginPage.setText("Login was Unsuccesful");
                    } else {
                        showToast("12");
                        updateUI();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
} //end of showToast

private void updateUI() {
    //go to student info page when sign in is correct
    showToast("13");
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentInfoPage.class);
    startActivity(i);
} //end of updateUI
```

}

When I run the app in an emulator and enter the user email and password and click the submit button it doesn't execute the FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener i.e any of the code between 'showToast("1");' and 'showToast("14");'. If it executes that code it should run the updateUI() function and go to another page.

Comment: Please state what is problem with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code **creates** an auth state listener, but never attaches it to anything. So that explains why the listener never gets called.

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        showToast("2");
        Authenticate(edtUsernameLoginPage, edtPasswordLoginPage, txtErrorLoginPage);
    }
    showToast("14")
};
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
```

Side note: I'd just put this in the `onCreate` outside of the `btnSubmitLoginPage.setOnClickListener`. Firebase automatically restores the authentication state of a user when the app restarts, so in many cases the user's previous login will be picked up in that case and they won't have to click the button.

Answer (score 1):

You havent initialised the FirebaseAuth object...
Before using the FirebaseAuth object

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           // ADD THIS LINE BEFORE YOU USE THE mAuth Object
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


}
```

You are actually trying to add the AuthStateListener to an uninitialized object of FirebaseAuth and that would give you a null pointer exception i guess.

Hope this solves the Issue.